# Gradle unzip archive with .git folders inside

Tags: gradle

Using `Gradle 2.11` and `JVM 1.8.0_77`.

The Gradle copy task for ziptrees doesn't seem to like dot folders inside zip-trees, as it ignores the `.git` folder entirely:

**Archive.zip:**

```
archive/someFile
archive/.manifest
archive/.git/objects/93/
archive/.git/objects/93/c426c3ffd836bfc0af36e6fd97a72b7b4f67be
archive/.git/objects/info/
archive/.git/objects/aa/
```

**Gradle task**

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
  def zipFile = file("archive.zip")
  from zipTree(zipFile)
  into workingDir
}
```

**Result:**

```
> $ gradle unzip
> $ find archive/.

archive/someFile
archive/.manifest
```

Using something like `include '**/.git'` also doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle copy task uses ant's DirectoryScanner which comes with a bunch of default excludes including `**/.git` and `**/.git/**`. See bottom of this post for full list of default excludes. See defect [GRADLE-1883](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1883), currently open and unresolved.

You can customize the default exclude list by removing the git entries from it, but any changes in your task will affect subsequent copy tasks, which can cause potential problems with tasks downhill.

The (rather ugly) safe workaround as suggested on that defect page is to remove default excludes in your task, and reset the excludes before your quit your task.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

task unzip(type: Copy) {
    doFirst {
      DirectoryScanner.defaultExcludes.each { DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude it }
      DirectoryScanner.addDefaultExclude 'something has to be in here or everything gets excluded'
    }

    doLast {
      DirectoryScanner.resetDefaultExcludes()
    }

    def zipFile = file("archive.zip")
    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into workingDir
}
```

---

Ant default exclude patterns:

```
**/%*%             
**/.git/**         
**/SCCS            
**/.bzr            
**/.hg/**          
**/.bzrignore      
**/.git            
**/SCCS/**         
**/.hg             
**/.#*             
**/vssver.scc      
**/.bzr/**         
**/._*             
**/#*#             
**/*~              
**/CVS             
**/.hgtags         
**/.svn/**         
**/.hgignore       
**/.svn            
**/.gitignore      
**/.gitmodules     
**/.hgsubstate     
**/.gitattributes  
**/CVS/**          
**/.hgsub          
**/.DS_Store       
**/.cvsignore
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I had same issue but not with unzip, rather with zip. I could not find this solution by that time and had no clue how to fix the "default exclude" thing in gradle. I found the same solution from ant and used ant task to create a ZIP that included the "default excluded .git" dir. I am pasting my workaround as under for people who might find it useful.

```
task createZip << {
    description 'Creates a zip file under build folder'
    ant.zip(destfile: filename) {
        fileset(dir: projectDir, defaultexcludes: 'no') {
            exclude(name: '*.zip, build/**, gradle/**, gradlew*, .idea/**')
    }
}
```

I just copied the code snippet, filename is a variable assigned a value in another part of build file. I have a list of excludes, you can have your own such list if needed. The only thing to mention is: How to call an ant task in a gradle task and then "defaultExcludes" parameter set to NO to serve the purpose.